# Custom post type that lets users create a set of posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, plugin-development, theme-development, custom-field

I'm trying to make my own slider plugin, and I'd like to have a set up similar to other slider plugins, where, rather than just having the ability to create individual slides, you can create separate sliders that contain groups of slides. How would you go about doing this when setting up a custom post type? Or is it a case of creating a new post type for each individual slider?

Thanks

Comment: This is up to you. You could have a CPT for the slider, one for the slides. Or use shortcodes, or ...

Comment: @kero A standard CPT isn't what I'm after though, basically I want the user to be able to create CPTs, which contain their own posts

Comment: But you are. As I said, you can have one CPT "Slider" and one CPT "Slide", which are connected via postmeta or parent/child. CPT means you have a strict structure and a defined input/output. This is true in your case, all sliders have the same structure (they contain slides)

Comment: @Kero Oh ok, I get what you're saying now, thanks. Do you know what functions I would need to use to set up a hierarchical CPT structure like that?